# Can't post a question

Tags: bug, status-completed

I didn't know where to post this, so sorry if this is the wrong place. Anyway, I am experiencing some technical difficulties with the EE StackExchange website (or maybe it's just my computer), but I cannot edit/discard a question nor I can include a schematic.

Everything worked fine when I was writing a question but when I wanted to include a schematic the whole thing crashed or froze or something... This is the picture, of how Ask Question page looks like:

[image: Ask Question page]

Now, it doesn't matter what I do, discard/log out, log in/change browser... I can't get rid of this problem, so I could rewrite the question...

Hope you can help.

Comment: I just started typing a question and Circuit Lab doesn't seem to be inserting schematics for me either at the moment. I thought you'd normally get a seperate error pop-up if this was the case but perhaps with a broken image link it's not letting you post.

Comment: I had a similar problem, I think over the weekend. I was using a version of Safari Circuit Lab says isn't supported, so I had put it down to that. In retrospect that was silly of me, because I have successfully created and inserted schematics before using the same browser.

Comment: Judging by [this getting asked](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/129255/lc-comparator-based-oscillator), I assume this has been resolved, or are you still experiencing issues?

Comment: Yes, it has been resolved, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

This should now be resolved and the fix is live across all sites. Sorry for the inconvenience; I broke it when modifying how the Markdown editor worked for Stack Snippets.